# #define syntax solution

Tags: c, syntax, c-preprocessor

I've defined the following, of course it's not correct...

```
#define SET_PIN_MODE_INPUT(DREG, PORT, PIN) (DREG &= ~_BV(PIN), PORT &= ~_BV(PIN))
#define LED_CLOCK_PIN (DDRB, PORTB, PB3)
```

and I want to use them like this:

```
SET_PIN_MODE_INPUT(LED_CLOCK_PIN)
```

So I need help with **C** syntax.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Indirection is required:

```
#define SET_PIN_MODE_INPUT_(DREG, PORT, PIN) (DREG &= ~_BV(PIN), PORT &= ~_BV(PIN))
#define SET_PIN_MODE_INPUT(ARGS) SET_PIN_MODE_INPUT_ ARGS

// Note that this is an object-like macro
#define LED_CLOCK_PIN /**/ (DDRB, PORTB, PB3)
```

With your current macros, you are passing a single argument to `SET_PIN_MODE_INPUT`, which requires three arguments.

This solution uses indirection to use the replacement list of `LED_CLOCK_PIN` as the argument list for the invocation of the real `SET_PIN_MODE_INPUT`.

Comment: "All problems in computer science can be solved by another level of indirection." - David Wheeler

Comment: @James, perhaps one should mention that the blank between the macro and the left `(` is essential for this to work. Might even be appropriate to glue a comment between the two to emphasize on that.

Comment: One more thing... is there any way to omit one of arguments? I have also two arguments: `#define SET_PIN_VALUE_LOW_(PORT, PIN) (PORT |= _BV(PIN))` and would still like to pass `LED_CLOCK_PIN` and DDRB param can be omitted.

Comment: I guess just write that arg and don't use it should be fine?

Comment: @JensGustedt:  I figured Pablo understood that since that macro was defined similarly in the question, but I updated the answer for the benefit of future readers (good idea).

Comment: @Pablo:  You don't have to use all macro arguments in the replacement list, so you can define such a macro as `#define SET_PIN_VALUE_LOW_(UNUSED, PORT, PIN) (PORT |= _BV(PIN))`

Answer (score 1):

You might want to define them as static inline functions in the header file, instead than defines. In this way you will get typecheck and you won't risk unexpected things to happen because of the preprocessor.

And the compiler will inline them.

Comment: This is for 8 bit slow microprocessor, so less cycles faster it will run.

Comment: @Pablo, an inlined function will typically cost you no cycle at all. Compilation might be some nanoseconds longer, though :)

Comment: In the loop and timer ISR, where all cycles are counting... even 1-2 cycles matters unfortunately.

Comment: @JensGustedt: `inline` is a compiler *hint*, not a command.  Hard to say if this is premature or not, but I work on embedded systems myself and you do have to consider the overhead of a function call at times.  That said, you also may have to consider the *size* of your code as well.  Everything's a trade off.  On a side note, it's nice to actually answer the question at hand instead of assuming the OP doesn't know what he is doing.

Comment: gcc has a flag to emit a warning when an "inline" function is not being inlined.